# How to integrate async calls in syncronous calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an abstract base class that reacts on `CollectionChanged` events from a `INotifyCollectionChanged` implementing instance. This abstract class declares abstract method that a deriving class has to override and fill with its functionality.

However, these abstract methods are Task methods (async), so i need to await them. But I can't await inside a lock statement, so I tried to do the lock in the caller of `OnSourceCollectionChanged`... but this will not solve the problem. 
Will `OnSourceCollectionChanged` produce race conditions with/without `lock`?
Is there a solution to the problem? Maybe there is an easier approach with **Rx**?

Here is my sample implementation:

```
public abstract class AbstractCollectionReplicator<TS, TD>
{
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    protected AbstractCollectionReplicator(INotifyCollectionChanged sourceCollection)
    {
        sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                // ensures the async operation is finished before entering the next
                lock (this.locker)
                {
                    this.OnSourceCollectionChanged(sender, args);
                }
            };
    }

    protected virtual async void OnSourceCollectionChanged(
        object sender, 
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                await this.OnSourceAdd(e.NewItems.OfType<TS>(), 
                                       e.NewStartingIndex);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                await this.OnSourceRemove(e.OldItems.OfType<TS>(), 
                                          e.OldStartingIndex);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                await this.OnSourceReplace(e.OldItems.OfType<TS>(), 
                                           e.NewItems.OfType<TS>(), 
                                           e.NewStartingIndex);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                await this.OnSourceMove(e.NewItems.OfType<TS>(), 
                                        e.OldStartingIndex, 
                                        e.NewStartingIndex);
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task OnSourceAdd<TS>(IEnumerable<TS> items, 
                                            int index);

    protected abstract Task OnSourceRemove<TS>(IEnumerable<TS> items, 
                                               int index);

    protected abstract Task OnSourceReplace<TS>(IEnumerable<TS> items, 
                                                IEnumerable<TS> enumerable, 
                                                int index);

    protected abstract Task OnSourceMove<TS>(IEnumerable<TS> items, 
                                             int fromIndex, 
                                             int toIndex);

    protected abstract Task OnSourceReset();
}
```

I want to do something like this in derived class(es):

```
    protected override async Task OnSourceAdd<TS>(IEnumerable<TS> items, 
                                                  int index)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var destinationItem = await this.someAsyncFunc(item);
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: "How to integrate async calls in syncronous calls" - simple: you don't; you can't; there are fundamentally different expectations from those two worlds. Calling `.Wait()` would *appear* to be a hack around it, but it would be a mistake and can cause a deadlock. The only sane approach here is: refactor your code so that you don't need to do this. Either sync all the way, or async all the way (well, you can safely call sync from async, obviously, but if it blocks: you aren't making good use of async)